# Pig Performance Measurement

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-pig

I wrote a Pig script and want to execute it on Hadoop cluster. How could I measure the total processing time? Is there any command that I could get the processing time from start to end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Added the `time` alternative.

To know how long it takes (in seconds):

```
time pig <options>
```

Another way to do it:

```
d1=$(date +%s)
pig <options>
d2=$(date +%s)
echo "$d2 - $d1" | bc
```

Or, in a single line:

```
d1=$(date +%s) ; pig <options> ; d2=$(date +%s) ; echo "$d2 - $d1" | bc
```

You can also just take a look at the output of pig. When you run a pig script in the command line, towards the end of the output you'll see:

```
HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
...
```

You can then subtract `FinishedAt - StartedAt`.

Comment: Your second method is what I would do, but for the first, why not just use `time`?

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus You are right, that's the way to do it. I just added `time` to my answer.